# Scala - Unexpected MapReduce Behavior - square of Even numbers

Tags: java, scala, mapreduce, scala-collections

I am learning Scala and am puzzled by the output of a *simple problem of
finding sum of squares of even integers between a range*.

**Code Snippet 1**:

```
val rangeOfNumbers = (1 to 5)
val listOfNumbers = rangeOfNumbers.toList
val squaresOfEvenNumbers = listOfNumbers
     .filter(element => element % 2 == 0)
     .reduce((total, element) => total+ (element * element))

println(squaresOfEvenNumbers)
Outputs: 18 -> which is clearly wrong

**EDIT** - Simulation:

I want to square the filtered even numbers - 2,4 and then add them to total variable

1: (total = 0, elem = 2) => 0 + (2 * 2) = 4
2. (total = 4, elem = 4) => 4 + (4 *4 ) = 20

Isn't this the expected behavior?
```

**Code Snippet 2**:

```
val rangeOfNumbers = (1 to 5)
val listOfNumbers = rangeOfNumbers.toList
val filteredEvenNumberSquaredList = listOfNumbers
    .filter(element => element % 2 == 0)
    .map(evenEle => evenEle * evenEle)
    .reduce((total, square) => total + square)

println(filteredEvenNumberSquaredList)
Outputs: 20 -> which is correct
```

***Can you explain what is wrong with first approach? What is happening internally?***

Comment: What makes you expect the `total` to be 0 on the first call? You are not passing `0` to `reduce` anywhere ... How can it possibly guess what you mean?

Comment: i made an assumption, it would initialize to zero. Bad assumption it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first call to the lambda you pass to `.reduce` the `total` is first element of the list, and `element` is the second one. You don't square the former, only the latter, so your result is off by 2.

You may want to consider using `.foldLeft` rather than `reduce`:

```
  list.foldLeft(0) { case (sum, elem) => sum + elem*elem }
```

It is the same as `.reduce`, except that it starts with the value you supply (`0` in this case), and is called the same way for every element of the list, including the first one (it will also work for empty lists, whereas `.reduce` would crash).

Alternatively, just `list.map(x => x*x).sum`

BTW, you can do all the filtering/mapping etc. on the range itself - no  need to convert it to list first:

```
 val squaresOfEvenNumbers = (1 to 5)
   .collect { case x if x % 2 == 0 => x*x }
   .sum
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'You don't square the former, only the latter, so your result is off by 2' 

I want to square the filtered even numbers - 2,4 and then add them to total variable

1: (total = 0, elem = 2) => 0 + (2 * 2) = 4
2. (total = 4, elem = 4) => 4 + (4 *4 ) = 20

Isn't this the expected behavior?

Comment: Well, it's not `(total = 0, elem = 2)` on the first call, it's `(total = 2, elem = 4)` - that's the problem.

Comment: I see, what you are saying is reduce function uses first element, ie, 2 as initial total value and then applies the function. So effectively, only single pass is done ie:

reduce((2,4) => 2 + 4*4) = 18.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `reduce` the doubling isn't applied to the first element:

```
List(2, 4).reduce((sum, el) => sum + el * el)
=> 2 + 4 * 4
=> 18
```

`reduce` (for nonempty lists) should satisfy:

```
l.reduce(op) == l.tail.foldLeft(l.head)(op)
```

Comment: curious, why is squaring not applied to first element? is this by design?

Comment: @aces. It's just the way that `reduce` works. You don't provide an initial element the way you do in `foldLeft`/`foldRight` and it needs to start somewhere so it grabs the first element in the collection and starts with that.